# Strange file browser - How to configure?

Tags: files, browser

I have an in-built file browser in DraftSight, with which I'm not familiar. How is it called and how could I configure/replace it? I need to see the places list on the left hand side.

[image: File Browser]

Comment: This file chooser is part of DraftSight, and there doesn't appear to be any options to change it or configure it. Your best bet would be to check out DraftSight's [Support and Services](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight/support-and-services/)

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  This is apparently not going to solve this problem, according to @ ElefantPhace.  I am not familiar with that app (or the language), so I answered blindly. /EndEdit

You can find out what the default file manager is by issuing the following command at a bash command prompt:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

If nautilus is the default, it should say:

```
nautilus*.desktop
```

If it is not nautilus, then make note of what the name is, and issue these commands:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus*.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.XXXXX.desktop show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktoxdg-mime default nautilus*.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-searchp.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Substitute the name of the file manager for `XXXXX`

If it *is* nautilus, then you should be able to configure it to show places, and whatever other changes you want either graphically, or if not available in the GUI, in dconf-editor under org.gnome.nautilus.

Comment: This may work, but it appears to be a file chooser that is part of DraftSight. May not be able to change it. It is, just downloaded DraftSight to check. It's part of the application. This will not work.

Comment: You're a lot more adventurous than I am. I was thrown off by the language, mainly, but it seems strange that they would use something different than the standard.  Wonder if it can be configured in a similar way as nautilus?